# How to reorder/reorganise variable attributes in a netcdf file?

Tags: shell, netcdf, nco

I need to move 'standard_name' to be the first attribute present in all my variables within a netcdf file.

I am yet to find the correct command but I am hoping it will be something fairly straight forward using NCO.

If I ncdump, this is the current output:

```
short heading(time) ;
        heading:data_max = 359.88f ;
        heading:long_name = "Ship heading" ;
        heading:data_min = 0.f ;
        heading:units = "degrees" ;
        heading:missing_value = 1.e+38f ;
        heading:add_offset = 179.94f ;
        heading:standard_name = "ship_heading" ;
        heading:scale_factor = -0.005491668f ;
    short depth(time, depth) ;
        depth:positive = "down" ;
        depth:long_name = "Depth" ;
        depth:data_min = 20.48f ;
        depth:units = "meter" ;
        depth:missing_value = 1.e+38f ;
        depth:data_max = 572.5f ;
        depth:standard_name = "depth" ;
        depth:add_offset = 296.49f ;
        depth:scale_factor = -0.008423671f ;
```

I need the output to be :

```
short heading(time) ;
        **heading:standard_name = "ship_heading" ;**
        heading:data_max = 359.88f ;
        heading:long_name = "Ship heading" ;
        heading:data_min = 0.f ;
        heading:units = "degrees" ;
        heading:missing_value = 1.e+38f ;
        heading:add_offset = 179.94f ;
        heading:scale_factor = -0.005491668f ;
    short depth(time, depth) ;
        **depth:standard_name = "depth" ;**
        depth:positive = "down" ;
        depth:long_name = "Depth" ;
        depth:data_min = 20.48f ;
        depth:units = "meter" ;
        depth:missing_value = 1.e+38f ;
        depth:data_max = 572.5f ;
        depth:add_offset = 296.49f ;
        depth:scale_factor = -0.008423671f ;
```

Comment: Out of interest can I ask why you might want to do this? kind of the whole idea of netcdf is that it doesn't matter what order variable metadata or variables records themselves come in...

Comment: @AdrianTompkins, Sure. It is purely about a neat appearance! When working with numerous data sets from many instruments that each have loads of variables it can get annoying scrolling through the ncdump to find what you're looking for. I like to keep the variable and attribute order consistent throughout, especially when preparing my metadata for storage. It seems there isn't a clear cut way to do this without rewriting the whole file, which I agree defeats the whole idea behind netcdf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree that the ideal place for `standard_name` is as the first or second attribute. Dumps are much more legible that way. You need to understand that attributes are stored and dumped in the order of their creation. NCO has no feature to re-arrange this order. The best solution is to alter the dataset writer so it creates `standard_name` before all other attributes. Or you can do something crazy like use `ncatted` to delete all the attributes and then re-add them in your desired order.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @CharlieZender! I thought that might be the case. No problem really, I just like to keep my metadata as consistent as possible :).